# R source without stopping rest of script from running

Tags: r, parallel-processing

Is there a way to source a different R script and continuing to execute the remainder of the current script without stoping to wait for the sourced scrip to finish?

eg.

Script 1 - run 00:00

source(Script2) - run 00:01

script 1 - end 00:05

script 2 - end 01:00

I hope this makes sense

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can accomplish this with `doParallel` like so:

```
require(doParallel)
scripts <- c('script1.r', 'script2.r')

foreach(x = 1:length(scripts)) %dopar%
{
  script <- scripts[x]
  source(script)
}
```

Which would run each script simultaneously on two different workers.

Comment: Thank you the problem is the second script would be initialized by the first script only at times so I cant always start them at the same time.

Comment: Do you mean to say that script2 is dependent on script1 finishing?

Comment: script 1 calls script 2 based on a condition being true. If script 2 is called I don't want script 1 to wait for script 1 to be completed. I just want it to open that script and keep on moving since script 2 will take significantly longer than script 1 to complete

Comment: hhmm...  In the situations where script 2 will run, is what follows in script 1 dependent on script 2 completing?

Comment: if answer is no, see @G5W comment to your original question.

Comment: Thank you! I think  @G5Ws comment is what im looking for.